# Proving Equivalence Of Darboux And Riemann Integral

Tags: calculus

Prove that if there is a bounded function $f(x)$ such that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a partition of $[a, b]$ such that $U-L<\epsilon$ then the function is Riemann Integrable on the interval $[a, b]$ where $U$ and $L$ denote the upper and lower sum respectively.
$$$$Suppose that $U_x$ and $L_x$ denote  the upper sum and lower sum of a partition with norm $x$. Now given that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a partition with a particular norm say $P$ such that $U_P-L_P <\epsilon$ and as we know that the upper sum decreases and the lower sum increases as the norm of the partition becomes smaller, so for all partitions of $[a, b]$ with norm $\delta<P$ we have $$U_{\delta}-L_{\delta}\leq U_P-L_P<\epsilon$$. Now as the upper sum is an increasing function of the norm of the partition and also as the upper sum is bounded from above and below as the function is bounded and the interval $[a, b]$ is finite so the upper sum must has some least lower bound say $I$ then we have $$\lim_{\Delta x_{\max} \to 0} U = I$$ $$$$(As if a function is increasing and bounded in $(c, c+a)$ for some $a>0$ then the limit $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)$ exists and is equal to the least lower bound of the function on the interval $(c, c+a)$) $$$$ and also as $U-L<\epsilon$ whenever the norm is less than $P$ where $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small so we have $$\lim_{\Delta x_{\max} \to 0} L=I$$ Hence the function $f(x)$ is integrable on the interval $[a, b]$ and its integral is equal to $I$.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct ?